# Sublime Text 3 Plugin HTML Popup Rendering

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am attempting to create a Sublime Text 3 plugin and want to display a popup that the user can choose options from. It seems like the only option available is view.show_popup which accepts a html string and some parameters.

Unfortunately the html engine is very limited, and doesn't accept pre-tags or allow inline styling of white-space css.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer for others. Some inline styling like color is supported, however "whitespace: pre" is ignored for some reason. To get around this I used manual formatting.

```
import sublime_plugin

class ExamplePlugin(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_text_command(self, view, command_name, args):
        if command_name == "run_macro_file":
            text = "some     spaced   out    text\n\nafter   newlines".replace(" ", "&nbsp;").replace("\n","<br>")
            view.show_popup(text, max_width=800, flags=0)
```